# Trouble with inline view SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to come up with a query for a warehouse that differentiates between pallets, cases or eaches in a warehouse management system. I saw another team uses this logic to do so which I've borrowed a snippet from however I'm stumped I'm missing a parenthesis somewhere according to Oracle.

```
SELECT
                       COMP_CODE, 
                       CUST_CODE, 
                       ITEM_CODE, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM1 IS NOT NULL THEN QTY1 * QTY2 * QTY3 * QTY4 * QTY5 ELSE NULL END AS QTY1, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM2 IS NOT NULL THEN QTY2 * QTY3 * QTY4 * QTY5 ELSE NULL END AS QTY2, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM3 IS NOT NULL THEN QTY3 * QTY4 * QTY5 ELSE NULL END AS QTY3, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM4 IS NOT NULL THEN QTY4 * QTY5 ELSE NULL END AS QTY4, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM5 IS NOT NULL THEN QTY5 ELSE NULL END AS QTY5, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM1 IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING((UOM1 + '    '), 1, 4) ELSE NULL END AS UOM1, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM2 IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING((UOM2 + '    '), 1, 4) ELSE NULL END AS UOM2,
                       CASE WHEN UOM3 IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING((UOM3 + '    '), 1, 4) ELSE NULL END AS UOM3, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM4 IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING((UOM4 + '    '), 1, 4) ELSE NULL END AS UOM4, 
                       CASE WHEN UOM5 IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING((UOM5 + '    '), 1, 4) ELSE NULL END AS UOM5
                 FROM
                       (
                       SELECT
                              H.COMP_CODE, 
                              H.CUST_CODE,
                              H.ITEM_CODE, 
                              H.QTY_BKD_PROF_CODE, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 1 THEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_QTY ELSE 1 END) AS QTY1, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 2 THEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_QTY ELSE 1 END) AS QTY2,
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 3 THEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_QTY ELSE 1 END) AS QTY3,
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 4 THEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_QTY ELSE 1 END) AS QTY4,
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 5 THEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_QTY ELSE 1 END) AS QTY5, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 1 THEN BK.SKU_CODE ELSE NULL END) AS UOM1, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 2 THEN BK.SKU_CODE ELSE NULL END) AS UOM2, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 3 THEN BK.SKU_CODE ELSE NULL END) AS UOM3, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 4 THEN BK.SKU_CODE ELSE NULL END) AS UOM4, 
                              MAX(CASE WHEN D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = 5 THEN BK.SKU_CODE ELSE NULL END) AS UOM5
                       FROM
                             M_ITEM_H AS H
                              INNER JOIN M_ITEM_D1 AS D1  
                                     ON H.COMP_CODE = D1.COMP_CODE AND H.CUST_CODE = D1.CUST_CODE AND H.ITEM_CODE = D1.ITEM_CODE
                              INNER JOIN M_QTY_BKD_PROF_D AS BK  
                                     ON H.COMP_CODE = BK.COMP_CODE AND H.QTY_BKD_PROF_CODE = BK.QTY_BKD_PROF_CODE AND D1.ITEM_QTY_BKD_LEV_NUM = BK.QTY_BKD_PROF_LEV_NUM
                       GROUP BY 
                              H.COMP_CODE,
                              H.CUST_CODE,
                              H.ITEM_CODE, 
                              H.QTY_BKD_PROF_CODE
                               )
```

This is the error.

```
    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 33 Column: 43
```

I've tried adding parenthesis at different points and get the same error.

Comment: Have you counted all `(` and `)`? Same number?

Comment: Are you sure that query is expected to run on Oracle? `SUBSTRING((UOM1 + '    '),` looks like non-Oracle to me.

Comment: Otherwise the syntax is valid ANSI SQL.

Comment: 21 ( and 21 ) checks out, good tip. I'm using the Oracle SQL developer application

Comment: The SUBSTRING still looks non-Oracle.

Comment: Instead of `CASE WHEN UOM1 IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING((UOM1 + '    '), 1, 4) ELSE NULL END` simply do `substr(UOM1 || '    ', 1, 4)`.

Comment: This is why **minimal** reproducible example isessential. [Divide and conquer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm)

Comment: Remove the "AS" between your table names and aliases.

Comment: Did you look at what was actually at character 43 of line 33? (OK, in what you've posted you seem to have deleted a space character, but it's still essentially pointing at the H in ` AS H` on that line). As Mike suggested, you can't use `AS` for table aliases in Oracle.